# uncomment the line upon search string while ignoring case in a file

Tags: sed, files, string, search, replace

Below is my cron file entries:

```
#Ansible: test2
*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation/detect401MORTEN/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation/detect401MORTEN/cron.out

# #Cron to auto restart MIMSJASPER tomcat server for all environments if it is down

#Ansible: test3
# */15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation/detect401MORTEN/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation/detect401MORTEN/cron.out
```

The below sed does not work for case insensitivity.

```
sed '/^#.*morten/s/^#//ig' wladmin.cron
```

Desired Output:

```
#Ansible: test2
*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation/detect401MORTEN/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation/detect401MORTEN/cron.out

 #Cron to auto restart MIMSJASPER tomcat server for all environments if it is down

#Ansible: test3
 */15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation/detect401MORTEN/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation/detect401MORTEN/cron.out
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the address selection case-insensitive - not the substitution command. If you have the GNU implementation of sed, you can apply the upper-case `I` modifier to an address regex like so:

```
sed '/^#.*morten/Is/^#//' wladmin.cron
```

The `g` substitution flag is not necessary - in fact, there can only be a single instance of an anchored pattern like `^#`.

See the [GNU sed manual: 4.3 selecting lines by text matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses).